# perl bash script outputing input

Tags: bash, perl

I'm trying to learn bash scripting. As an exercise, I'm getting the Alt text and URL of the Google doodle.

I am stuck on using perl to parse out the link URL. I have it finding and outputting the alt text and url, but it is also outputting the whole webpage too. It does the same thing when I just put it in shell.

```
curl -s google.com --Location | perl -pe 's|.*<img.*alt="(.*?)".*src="(.*?)".*>.*|\1 http://google.com\2|'
```

How can I get this to stop outputting the webpage.

Note that I tried separating these to make sure it was perl doing to output of the page and not something with curl. It is definitely the perl part. If there is a better way to do this, let me know. The goal is to output the alt text and URL of the doodle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an ugly way to do things, but it may work if you print each line from the web page where a substitution has been made

```
perl -ne 'print if s/<img.*alt="(.*?)".*src="(.*?)".*>/$1 http://google.com$2/'
```

But it would be cleaner to do just a regex match and use negated character classes instead of non-greedy quantifiers

```
perl -ne 'print "$1 http://google.com$2\n" if /<img[^<>]+alt="([^"]+)"[^<>]+src="([^"]+)"/'
```

But both of these rely on (amongst other things) all of the contents of the opening `<img>` tag appearing on a single line, which isn't necessarily true. They will also report the contents of *every* `<img>` element in the page that has both an `alt` and a `src` attribute.